# Difference in URL between question itself and its edit page

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, hyperlinks

The URL of a question is like this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/undo-the-last-git-commit
```

The *edit* page of that page is like this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/posts/927358/edit
```

Why is the first part after the domain `/questions` for the question itself, and `/posts` for the edit page?

Wouldn't something like `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/undo-the-last-git-commit/edit` make more sense?

Comment: No, it would not. The questions-syntax is geared to producing speaking URLs (all after `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/` is free-form, and if left out even that final slash is optional). The posts-syntax is instead geared to short URLs for doing stuff, which mostly makes equal sense for questions and answers.

Comment: @Deduplicator Any source?

Comment: Merely an observation. Though the SE guys are good about not abandoning/repurposing parts of their namespace on these sites, which would lead to confusion and broken links.